# Parsing through HTML in a dictionary

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to pull table data from the following website: https://msih.bgu.ac.il/md-program/residency-placements/

While there are no table tags I found the common tag to pull individual segments of the table to be div class=accord-con

I made a dictionary where the keys are the graduation year (ie, 2019, 2018, etc), and the values is the html from each div class-accord con.

I'm stuck and don't know how to parse the html within the dictionary. My goal is to have separate lists of the specialty, hospital, and location for each year. I don't know how to move forward.

Below is my working code:

```
import numpy as np
import bs4 as bs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://msih.bgu.ac.il/md-program/residency-placements/').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

headers = soup.find_all('div', class_={'accord-head'})
grad_yr_list = []
for header in headers:
    grad_yr_list.append(header.h2.text[-4:])

rez_classes = soup.find_all('div', class_={'accord-con'})

data_dict = dict(zip(grad_yr_list, rez_classes))
```

Here is a sample of what my dictionary looks like:

```
{'2019': <div class="accord-con"><h4>Anesthesiology</h4><ul><li>University at Buffalo School of Medicine, Buffalo, NY</li></ul><h4>Emergency Medicine</h4><ul><li>Aventura Hospital, Aventura, Fl</li></ul><h4>Family Medicine</h4><ul><li>Louisiana State University School of Medicine, New Orleans, LA</li><li>UT St Thomas Hospitals, Murfreesboro, TN</li><li>Sea Mar Community Health Center, Seattle, WA</li></ul><h4>Internal Medicine</h4><ul><li>Oregon Health and Science University, Portland, OR</li><li>St Joseph Hospital, Denver, CO </li></ul><h4>Obstetrics-Gynecology</h4><ul><li>Jersey City Medical Center, Jersey City, NJ</li><li>New York Presbyterian Brooklyn Methodist Hospital, Brooklyn, NY</li></ul><h4>Pediatrics</h4><ul><li>St Louis Children’s Hospital, St Louis, MO</li><li>University of Maryland Medical Center, Baltimore, MD</li><li>St Christopher’s Hospital, Philadelphia, PA</li></ul><h4>Surgery</h4><ul><li>Mountain Area Health Education Center, Asheville, NC</li></ul><p></p></div>,
 '2018': <div class="accord-con"><h4>Anesthesiology</h4><ul><li>NYU School of Medicine, New York, NY</li></ul><h4>Emergency Medicine</h4><ul><li>Kent Hospital, Warwick, Rhode Island</li><li>University of Connecticut School of Medicine, Farmington, CT</li><li>University of Texas Health Science Center at San Antonio, San Antonio, TX</li><li>Vidant Medical Center East Carolina University, Greenville, NC</li></ul><h4>Family Medicine</h4><ul><li>University of Kansas Medical Center, Wichita, KS</li><li>Ellis Hospital, Schenectady, NY</li><li>Harrison Medical Center, Seattle, WA</li><li>St Francis Hospital, Wilmington, DE </li><li>University of Virginia, Charlottesville, VA</li><li>Valley Medical Center, Renton, WA</li></ul><h4>Internal Medicine</h4><ul><li>Oregon Health and Science University, Portland, OR</li><li>Virginia Commonwealth University Health Systems, Richmond, VA</li><li>University of Chicago Medical Center, Chicago, IL</li></ul><h4>Obstetrics-Gynecology</h4><ul><li>St Francis Hospital, Hartford, CT</li></ul><h4>Pediatrics</h4><ul><li>Case Western University Hospitals Cleveland Medical Center, Cleveland, OH</li><li>Jersey Shore University Medical Center, Neptune City, NJ</li><li>University of Maryland Medical Center, Baltimore, MD</li><li>University of Virginia, Charlottesville, VA</li><li>Vidant Medical Center East Carolina University, Greenville, NC</li></ul><h4>Preliminary Medicine Neurology</h4><ul><li>Howard University Hospital, Washington, DC</li></ul><h4>Preliminary Medicine Radiology</h4><ul><li>Maimonides Medical Center, Bronx, NY</li></ul><h4>Preliminary Medicine Surgery</h4><ul><li>Providence Park Hospital, Southfield, MI</li></ul><h4>Psychiatry</h4><ul><li>University of Maryland Medical Center, Baltimore, MI</li></ul><p></p></div>,
```

My ultimate goal is to pull this data into a pandas dataframe with the following columns: grad year, specialty, hospital, location

Comment: _I'm stuck and don't know how to parse the html within the dictionary._ - Just parse from string: `>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(myHtmlString)`

Comment: did you check what you have in dict? As for me it is not string but BS object which doesn't need to be parsed and you can use it with `value.find()`, `value.find_all()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have dictionary with BS elements (`'bs4.element.Tag'`) and you don't have to parse them.

You can directly uses `find()`, `find_all()`, etc.

```
for key, value in data_dict.items():
    print(type(value), key, value.find('h4').text)
```

Result

```
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'> 2019 Anesthesiology
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'> 2018 Anesthesiology
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'> 2017 Anesthesiology
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'> 2016 Emergency Medicine
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'> 2015 Emergency Medicine
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'> 2014 Anesthesiology
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'> 2013 Anesthesiology
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'> 2012 Emergency Medicine
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'> 2011 Emergency Medicine
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'> 2010 Dermatology
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'> 2009 Emergency Medicine
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'> 2008 Family Medicine
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'> 2007 Anesthesiology
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'> 2006 Triple Board (Pediatrics/Adult Psychiatry/Child Psychiatry)
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'> 2005 Family Medicine
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'> 2004 Anesthesiology
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'> 2003 Emergency Medicine
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'> 2002 Family Medicine
```

---

Full code:

```
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://msih.bgu.ac.il/md-program/residency-placements/').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

headers = soup.find_all('div', class_={'accord-head'})
grad_yr_list = []
for header in headers:
    grad_yr_list.append(header.h2.text[-4:])

rez_classes = soup.find_all('div', class_={'accord-con'})

data_dict = dict(zip(grad_yr_list, rez_classes))

for key, value in data_dict.items():
    print(type(value), key, value.find('h4').text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite close to finding the end result. Once you have paired the years with the student placement data, simply apply an extraction function to the latter.:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
from selenium import webdriver
_d = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
_d.get('https://msih.bgu.ac.il/md-program/residency-placements/')
d = soup(_d.page_source, 'html.parser')
def placement(block):
   r = block.find_all(re.compile('ul|h4'))
   return {r[i].text:[b.text for b in r[i+1].find_all('li')] for i in range(0, len(r)-1, 2)}

result = {i.h2.text:placement(i) for i in d.find_all('div', {'class':'accord-head'})}
print(result['Class of 2019'])
```

Output:

```
{'Anesthesiology': ['University at Buffalo School of Medicine, Buffalo, NY'], 'Emergency Medicine': ['Aventura Hospital, Aventura, Fl'], 'Family Medicine': ['Louisiana State University School of Medicine, New Orleans, LA', 'UT St Thomas Hospitals, Murfreesboro, TN', 'Sea Mar Community Health Center, Seattle, WA'], 'Internal Medicine': ['Oregon Health and Science University, Portland, OR', 'St Joseph Hospital, Denver, CO\xa0'], 'Obstetrics-Gynecology': ['Jersey City Medical Center, Jersey City, NJ', 'New York Presbyterian Brooklyn Methodist Hospital, Brooklyn, NY'], 'Pediatrics': ['St Louis Children’s Hospital, St Louis, MO', 'University of Maryland Medical Center, Baltimore, MD', 'St Christopher’s Hospital, Philadelphia, PA'], 'Surgery': ['Mountain Area Health Education Center, Asheville, NC']}
```

Note: I ended up using `selenium` because for me, the returned HTML response from `requests.get` did not included the rendered student placement data.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to pandas once you get the soup, then parse the necessary information

```
df = pd.DataFrame(soup)
df['grad_year'] = df[0].map(lambda x: x.text[-4:])
df['specialty'] = df[1].map(lambda x: [i.text for i in x.find_all('h4')])
df['hospital'] = df[1].map(lambda x: [i.text for i in x.find_all('li')])
df['location'] = df[1].map(lambda x: [''.join(i.text.split(',')[1:]) for i in x.find_all('li')])
```

You will have to do some pandas magic after that

Comment: how to i get all the placements for each year, with you method i only get the first match in each year thanks!

Comment: tried your solution and got the following error message: "'Doctype' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: which line failed?

Comment: second line failed

Comment: for `specialty`? I can't seem to get that error, `type(df[1][0])` is a `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know pandas. The following code can get the data in the table. I don't know if this will meet your needs.

```
import requests
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc 
url = 'https://msih.bgu.ac.il/md-program/residency-placements/'
response = requests.get(url)
doc = SimplifiedDoc(response.text)
divs = doc.getElementsByClass('accord-head')
datas={}
for div in divs:
  grad_year = div.h2.text[-4:]
  rez_classe = div.getElementByClass('accord-con')
  h4s = rez_classe.h4s # get h4
  for h4 in h4s:
    if not h4.next: 
      continue
    lis = h4.next.lis
    specialty = h4.text
    hospital = [li.text for li in lis]
    datas[grad_year]={'specialty':specialty,'hospital':hospital}
for data in datas:
  print (data,datas[data])
```

Comment: thank you! the resulting dictionary only has one element. how do i change the loop to add all of the tags to the dictionary?